# Using Google Apps in Summer 15

Tags: summer-15, google-drive

I have had Google Apps configured and working in a Spring 15 org, however once deployed to a Summer 15 org the integration is no longer working. Specifically, the process to add a Google document to a Salesforce contact record appears to be broken.

After clicking the "Add Google Doc" button on the documents related list and populating the Google Doc URL field, I now receive the following error:

> "This Google Doc is not part of the xxxxx.com domain. Please add this
>   Google Doc from your Google Apps account at xxxxx.com domain."

I am aware that Google have deprecated AuthSub authentication, and Salesforce have launched Files Connect. I have set up Files Connect (including OAuth2.0) and I am able to add a Google Doc to the Library in SF and then attach this to a contact record using a Chatter file post, however my preference would be to add a Google Doc directly to a record, without first needing to add the doc to the Library.

My question is:
Does anyone know if Salesforce have withdrawn the original "Add Google Docs to salesforce.com" configuration option?  I have found no mention of this in Summer 15 release notes.

Additionally, does anyone have a straight forward way to attach a Google doc to a record, using Files Connect, that doesn't require adding the Google doc to the Library first?

Answer (score 2):

known issue ; see this article : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YqIAAU